# Casting a String property to int in Spring config file

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I have a properties file test.properties

```
HOST = http://localhost
PORT = 1234
```

In my config file I am passing the values from the properties file to a bean constructor-arg.

```
<util:properties id="nodeProperty"
  location="classpath:config/test.properties" />
<context:property-placeholder
    properties-ref="nodeProperty" />

<bean id="client" class="com.abc.client.ReadWrite">
    <constructor-arg value="${HOST}" index="0"/>
    <constructor-arg value="${PORT}" index="1" type="int"/>
</bean>
```

When I run this I get the following error

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type
[int]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.lang.String] to 
  required type [int]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required   type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8002;"
```

Comment: Do you have semicolon in your port property? You dont need to specify type, spring will auto convert it. Also please paste actual input dont manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the end of error message  -  For input string: "8002;"
I think it is incorrect value for PORT property.